# Parallel sql queries without Task Parallel Library?

Tags: sql, .net, multithreading, linq, parallel-processing

My task is to optimize a pretty heavy query (~10 000 rows). I would like to use multithreading, so each of the threads processed and returned a specific range of data, for example, I create 3 threads. 
1st thread processes and returns first 100 rows, 
2nd - next 100 rows, 
3rd - next 100 rows
When a thread has finished it's work, it takes next 100 rows and so on till there are no more data to be returned.

I've read about TPL, but it has been a native functionality since .NET 4.0, but my project is based on 3.5. Also I read about Reactive library, which has TPL functionality for .NET 3.5, but was unable to get it working for me.

It boils down to this: how do I break the query down to pieces, which could be executed by a number of threads? (possibly in a loop)

P.S I prefer LINQ, but a simple textual script is acceptable as well

Comment: That's *not* a heavy query, if it takes too long you should check your indexes and SQL statements.

Comment: The task I am working on would be a base for a real live software with millions of rows. I agree with you, 10k really isn't that heavy. This code have to be able to handle much heavier queries though :)

Comment: Heavy queries are best handled by the database server. Why do you want to pull all the data on the client-side for processing? If you have an ETL scenario, why not use SSIS? It's built for this very purpose

Comment: To be honest, I don't even know what this thing is going to be used for. It won't be for ETL process though. I was simply given a task to figure out parallel queries on .NET 3.5 (and improve my knowledge with SQL, I guess), that's all :)

Comment: I suggest you find out how it's going to be used then and what they meant by `parallel queries`. It makes a *lot* of difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some tinkering I found a pretty basic way to achieve multithreaded query processing without TPL on .NET Framework 3.5

My approach:

- Get the total row count of the table
- Batch size = row count / thread count
- Create the threads so each of them would get a specific row subset depending on the batch size. Info for [SQL servers < 2012 Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) and [2012+ Here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) 
  *(example: table has 300 rows, we use 3 threads, each thread would return a batch of 100 rows)*
- Start all the threads and wait for them to complete (I used a flag)
- Dispose of the threads
- *Don't forget to add "MultipleActiveResultSets=True" (MARS) when writing your connection string or db connection configuration. This will allow multiple batches on a single connection*

This one works quite well for me. Please comment on this, if you have a better idea on how to approach multithreaded querying on .NET 3.5

Comment: Why do you want to process the results on the client side like this? 10k is a *small* result set, paging shouldn't be needed at all. A very quick&dirty solution would be to load all data in memory then use multiple threads to process it. "Parallel queries" only have meaning for terabyte-sized loading operations

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos answered in the question comments